# Specify the order for groups when using unite from dplyr for plotting with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, ggpubr

I wanted to do something like this

[Add multiple comparisons using ggsignif or ggpubr for subgroups with no labels on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54140346/how-can-i-add-multiple-pvalues-to-ggplot-grouped-boxplot?answertab=active#tab-top)

I got this far:

Packages and Example data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggpol)
library(ggsignif)

example.df <- data.frame(species = sample(c("primate", "non-primate"), 50, replace = TRUE),
                         treated = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 50, replace = TRUE),
                         gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 50, replace = TRUE), 
                         var1 = rnorm(50, 100, 5))
```

Levels

```
example.df$species <- factor(example.df$species, 
                             levels = c("primate", "non-primate"), labels = c("p", "np"))
example.df$treated <- factor(example.df$treated, 
                             levels = c("No", "Yes"), labels = c("N","Y"))
example.df$gender <- factor(example.df$gender, 
                            levels = c("male", "female"), labels = c("M", "F"))
```

Since I have had no luck in getting either `ggsignif` or `ggpubr` to work with placing the significant groups correctly when the groups they need to refer to are not explicitly named in the x-axis (as they are subgroups of each variable in the x-axis and are indicated only in the fill legend and not the x-axis, I tried this instead.

```
example.df %>% 
  unite(groups, species, treated, remove = F, sep= "\n") %>% 
  {ggplot(., aes(groups, var1, fill= treated)) + 
     geom_boxjitter() +
     facet_wrap(~ gender, scales = "free") +
     ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons =  combn(sort(unique(.$groups)), 2, simplify = F),
                           step_increase = 0.1)}
```

I get this,

Faceted plot with significance values computed for every group
[image: Faceted plot with significance values computed for every group]

However, the order of the combined groups on the x -axis is not how I want it. I want to order it with p/N, np/N, p/Y, np/Y for each facet.

How do I do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: Creating a new variable using mutate and making it an ordered factor with my preferred plotting order solves.

```
example.df %>% 
  unite(groups, species, treated, remove = F, sep= "\n") %>% 
  mutate(groups2 = factor(groups, levels = c("p\nN", "np\nN", "p\nY", "np\nY"),
                          ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  {ggplot(., aes(groups2, var1, fill= treated)) +
     geom_boxjitter() + 
     facet_wrap(~gender,scales = "free") +
     ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = combn(sort(unique(.$groups2)), 2, simplify = F), 
                           step_increase = 0.1)}
```

But I am still looking for solutions to not having to use `unite` at all and keeping the original factors and still get significance values to plot using `ggsignif` or `ggpubr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default parameters for `interaction` (from the base package) appear to give the factor ordering you are looking for:

[image: result]

```
example.df %>%
  mutate(groups = interaction(species, treated, sep = "\n")) %>%
  {ggplot(., aes(groups, var1, fill= treated)) + 
    geom_boxjitter() +
    facet_wrap(~ gender, scales = "free") +
    geom_signif(comparisons = combn(sort(as.character(unique(.$groups))), 2, simplify = F),
                step_increase = 0.1)}
```